# Kubernetes deployment status in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-deployment

I am writing a Jenkins Global pipeline library where I have a stage to deploy my docker image to K8s cluster.
So after building my docker image during CI process I am promoting(deploying) the image to multiple environments(sequentially lower to higher).
So, to get the correct status of deployment after running

```
kubectl apply -f Application-k8s-file.yaml
```

I used following command in a shell step.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment_name
```

Things goes well if my deployment does not have error but if my deployment has some error(might be some code bug, application does not start) then this command `kubectl rollout status deployment <deployment name>` runs infinitely(as k8s retries again and again to redeploy) and my Jenkins job runs infinitely(till the Job timeout).

So to find a hack I tried a logic to put the timeout on this command and calculations are something like this:

timeout = (number of pods * liveness probe time + number of pods* 10) seconds

Not sure if this calculation is correct or not.

My code snippet looks like this

```
        sh(returnStdout: true,script:"#!/bin/sh +e\n timeout --preserve-status ${timeout_value} kubectl rollout status deployment ${deploymentName} --kubeconfig='/opt/kubernetes-secrets/${env}/kubeconfig' 2>tmpfile; echo \$? > tmpfile1")
    def readThisFile = readFile "tmpfile1.txt"

def var=readThisFile.toInteger()

           if(var==0)
           {
             echo "deployment successful"
           }
       else{"do something else"}
```

This works well initially but later I find that k8s "kubectl rollout status deployment " command doesn't give exit code 0 until all the pods get scheduled and old get terminated completely which sometimes take time.

What I basically want is a minimal calculated timeout value.

My K8s file have parameters like this:

```
   spec:
     minReadySeconds: 30

    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /ping
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 45
      periodSeconds: 5
      timeoutSeconds: 60
    name: test-dummyservice
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 120
      timeoutSeconds: 60
```

I did not find anything specific related to this in K8s documentation. Anyone facing same challenge?

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at `progressDeadlineSeconds`. Once this exceeds the deadline the `rollout status` will exit out.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment ng                                                                                                                      
Waiting for rollout to finish: 2 out of 7 new replicas have been updated...
error: deployment "ng" exceeded its progress deadline
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds

Answer (score 3):

You can add the `timeout` flag like below, here is the doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands

```
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment_name --watch --timeout=5m
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to wait for the rollout to finish then you can use `--watch=false`.

```
kubectl rollout status deployment deployment_name --watch=false
```

Now, you can check with this command for a duration with specific interval.

Comment: That means, your deployment should change its status to failed/succeeded in a period

Comment: Thanks @aerokite for responding, but this solution doesn't work in my case I need the correct timeout as to proceed the artefact to higher env. Basically what I want is either the rollout status says I am not successful in minimal time and jenkins job failed or it should say I am pass and job promotes the artefact to next env. When I run this command and get the exit status it is always 0, though I can grep "Waiting" or "successfully" keyword from the output and based on that I can put some logic. Any better way of doing this?

Comment: This timeout period value I am looking for.

Comment: Can you set `MinReadySeconds` in DeploymentSpec?

Comment: Deleting this answer as its not what you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164550/discussion-between-vaibhav-jain-and-aerokite).